# DDR3 Termination resistor value regarding

Tags: memory, ddr3

In a design, my senior put a 49.9ohm termination resistor to terminate the control, address, and control lines.Here I can't find the correct explation for this.

My question is,
1.How to choose the termination resistor for DDR3?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Read application notes. Many of them!

Longer answer: **It's complicated**

Impedance matching in DDR3 designs is always a compromise between power consumption and susceptibility to EMI.

If you're using DDR3 memory modules you have to consider that they already contain termination resistors so your options are very limited.

But if you're using discrete memory chips, you have more choices.

You need to consider the impedance of your traces (trace width, board layer stackup, trace spacing) which should be tightly controlled in the layout.
To lower you get the impedance, the higher the current and therefore the power requirements but also the less prone your design is to suffering from interference.

Just search for [ddr3 impedance matching](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=ddr3%20impedance%20matching) and you'll find data sheets, application notes and other stuff people have asked here on SA. And to sum it up: there is no neat little formula to calculate that resistance.

Comment: In DDR3,they mentioned already many ODT options are available.Then why we should add termination resistor at the end of the signals?

Comment: @GaneshP because the schedule n die termination can't do everything. I can only guess bit I assume it's because of thermal issues. With the number of data, address and contol lines current trough all the resistors van reach several 100mA which van lead to a high thermal load.. and you don't want hot DRAM because that increases leakage...

Comment: One more question sir.In another DDR3L design they connected one end of the capacitor in one voltage level and another end another voltage rail instead of connecting it to ground.What is the purpose of that?They just using the difference between that voltage rails?

Comment: Generally ODT is for DQ/DQS/DM only. There are some ICs that have optional termination for ACC, in that case you enable it on the last IC of a chain and disable it for the others. The value, and the trace impedance, depends on the topology. For a single long chain, it is common to build a 50 ohm system (traces and termination) because board fabricators understand how to make these reliably, and you can analyze them with a 50 ohm network analyzer.